Dolt: How to import Triggers from MySQL
When I create a MySQL dump that includes triggers, I get lines looking like
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`example_user`@`%`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `tablename_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `tablename` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `schema`.`log_tablename` (action, id, value) VALUES ('update', NEW.id, NEW.value) */;;
DELIMITER ;

If I try to import that dump file into Dolt, I get an Error along the lines of
failed to prepare import job: syntax error at position 12 near 'DELIMITER'

How can I fix this?
Manually running the Trigger Create statements one by one is possible, but would be extremely time consuming, as we probably have a hundred of them in our database.
